# Qt Creator, C++, Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, qt-creator

I'm a C++ developer and I would like to develop applications for OSX and IOS with my Mac.
I'd like to use Xcode to achieve these goals but apparently the best solution (that involves C++) is Qt Creator. (Let me know if I'm wrong)

Can I use the free version of QT Creator (community - no license fee) to code in C++ for iOS/OSX and publish my apps on the Apple Store or do I need the indie mobile license?

Can QT be integrated in Xcode?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting into OS X and iOS development using Qt 5.3.2. It looks like that you use Qt Creator to create an iOS (or OS X) project. Then, Qt Creator makes use of Xcode for the build.

I've successfully created a OS X project using Qt Creator. It is a QML project with a C++ plugin that I created. So, I believe that you can use Qt Creator to create a pure C++ project for OS X. But give Qt Creator a shot and see if that is true.

Now, for iOS, I think you'll have to create a QML project. You can always use C++ to add functionality. However, I am having trouble getting a C++ plugin to compile in an iOS project. But, I think that it is just a matter of finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow for OSX/iOS app development is quite simple. You develop your application as usual in Qt Creator. Each time `qmake` is called on your code, it created an Xcode project `xxx.xcodeproj` where `xxx` is the application name specified in your `.pro` file.

Hence, when you have completed the development process, you can open such a project and finalize the app packaging/submission via xcode. The created project includes all the necessary framework dependencies and is ready to be `archive`d, i.e. packaged for AppStore submission. The submission is a tedious task, [see here for example](http://www.scribd.com/doc/47462278/iOS-App-Submission-Checklist).

You can absolutely submit the app to the AppStore, even with the community license. Mind that you are subject to LGPL. This aspect is treated in full detail in [this recent blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/10/01/benefits-of-the-indie-mobile-licensing/).

Answer (score -1):

If you're developing for iOS and OS X only - use native tools, i. e. Xcode. Qt library and Qt Creator IDE are best used for cross-platform development, but not for native OS X development.

Comment: Ok but how can I develop apps for iOS under Xcode in C++? They require Objective-C...